# Delete Tuple Pairs if they are the same

Tags: python, list, compare, tuples

I have a problem with tuples in python. I have the following tuple list:

```
gamma2 = [[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')],[('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')]]
```

Now, the parts `[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')]` and `[('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')]` are the same for me and also `[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')]` and `[('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')]`.

So I want to delete one of these double entries in my list, but I don't know how.

I've tried with hash tables and set, but the problem is, that this tuple pair is not the same for the hash table and it will be added by `gamma2.add()`.

So do you have an idea?

Comment: Do you care about the ordering of the lists?

Comment: What doesn't work if you use sets? Instead of a list of tuples, have a set of sets, then you'll automatically not have the duplicates.

Comment: Yes, the ordering is important 
@RobinZigmond If I work sets, I will have a duplicate because 
[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')] and [('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')] are not the same for the hash table.
They have a different hash value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use tuple ans set

```
gamma2 = [[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')],[('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')]]
set([tuple(set(x)) for x in gamma2])
```

for some case it will be better to use `sorted` instead inside `set` (thanks @rockikz)

```
set([tuple(sorted(x)) for x in gamma2])
```

and third solution is to use `frozenset`

```
set([frozenset(x) for x in gamma2])
```

will give you the result:

```
{(('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')), (('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u'))}
```

set - list of unique values

- the set inside loop - need to to lead the items to make them equal
- next use tuple only as sugar to make outer set
- and the last set we use to get unique values

and if you want the same type in the result you can do it:

```
[list(y) for y in set([tuple(set(x)) for x in gamma2])]
```

will give you

```
[[('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')], [('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')]]
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks, that works! 
So can you maybe please explain me, what's going on there?

Comment: added details in the answer

Comment: Why this isn't working for me?
I'm getting `{(('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')), (('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')), (('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')), (('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w'))}` as a result here on windows, Python 3.6.6 64 bits

Comment: And working instead on linux same python version, can you explain this please?

Comment: And works just fine when I add `sorted()`, like this: `set([ tuple(sorted(set(x))) for x in gamma2 ])`

Comment: @rockikz i tried my solution in python 3.6.1 and in python 3.7 and it works fine but your idea with sorted looks interested. I can add it to the answer if you do not mind?

Comment: @Armani42 you should accept the answer if it is work for you. It need for other who will search the same solution.

Comment: @BearBrown What do you mean? I accept it, thank you very much, appreciate it! :)